# How to read passwd(5) manual page?

Tags: linux, kali-linux, man

When I do `man passwd`, it opens the manual for **PASSWD(1)**. So what is **PASSWD(5)** and how to open its man page?

Comment: try man 5 passwd

Comment: Also use a different Gnu/Linux distro. Kali is for experts. There are may other easier to use distros. They would not help with this problem, but you will bump into many others, that you will not solve so easily. Debian is a good distro, and contains most of the packages that you may need.